# Is there a Ubuntu network hacking derivative?

Tags: networking, derivatives

Is there a Ubuntu derivative who have facilities like network hacking that developed by community / unofficial ubuntu derivatives?

Comment: What do you mean by network hacking?

Comment: I mean an Ubuntu derivative with some tools to hack a network

Comment: In my opinion this is off topic as there is no such official derivative...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BlackBuntu, BackTrack, nUbuntu... But please, don't use them for dirty jobs, ok?